# Can any finite group of order $n$ be embedded in $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, general-linear-group

If $G$ is a finite group of order $n$, it can be embedded in $S_n$ by Cayley's theorem and therefore in $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ and $SL_{n+1}(\mathbb{Z})$. Can $G$ be embedded in $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question so I thought I should share.

The main idea is that once we can embedd $S_n$ in $GL_{n-1}(\mathbb{Z})$, it is easy to create a injective morphism from $GL_{n-1}(\mathbb{Z})$ into $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ by using the extra coefficient to cancel out the determinant.

To embedd $S_n$ in $GL_{n-1}(\mathbb{Z})$ we will consider the permutation matrixes in $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$.
Firstly, we notice that the vector $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that is made of only ones is an eigenvector of any permutation matrix.
If $e_1, \dots , e_n$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, let $B$ be the basis $(X, e_2, \dots , e_n)$ in which a permutation matrix will take this shape:

$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & * \\
0 & M(\sigma) 
\end{bmatrix}  $

Where $\sigma$ is a permutation. We may then check that M is an injective morphism from $S_n$ to $GL_{n-1}(\mathbb{Z})$

Comment: You can (and probably should) accept your own answer!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes for $n$ odd, since $S_n$ embeds into $SL_n(\mathbb Z)$ - indeed, for $\sigma\in S_n$ let $P_\sigma$ be the corresponding permutation matrix. Since $\det P_\sigma=\operatorname{sgn}\sigma$ and $n$ is odd, $Q_\sigma:=(\operatorname{sgn}\sigma)\cdot P_\sigma\in SL_n(\mathbb Z)$ and
$$Q_\sigma Q_\tau=(\operatorname{sgn}\sigma)(\operatorname{sgn}\tau)\cdot P_\sigma P_\tau=(\operatorname{sgn}\sigma\tau)\cdot P_{\sigma\tau}=Q_{\sigma\tau}.$$
I don't see how it could be generalized to even $n$.

Comment: @M.Van Your matrix doesn't commute with $P_\sigma$s, so this won't give an embedding of $S_n$.

Comment: I failed to mention that the result should actually be true - even for even $n$ - as it is a question I have been asked to answer. It should even be doable with rather basic group theory knowledge. But no one I have asked has found a proof of it yet.